# Restructuring data received from JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making a JSON call and receiving data and inputting the data received into some HTML. However I don't think this is the best way to return the data. It's seems like a bit of a hack as I'm injecting a bunch of HTML in my jQuery. I'm also adding an image inside of my jQuery cause I want it to appear between some of the JSON data that is getting returned. Ideally I'd like my html to loop through and generate this info into the `chatInfo` div. Anybody have any ideas how to better do this?

```
$.getJSON("/services/chatInfo.json?user=manual" + mediaTypes + locationTypes, function(data) {

         var items = [];
            $.each( data.media, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<div class='chatInfo'><h6 id='" + key + "'>" + val.displayName + "</h6>" );
            items.push( "<aside><img src='/google.png'></aside><p>" + val.hours + "</p></div>" );
            });

            $("<div>").html(items.join("")).appendTo( "#chatInfo" );
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

A much more maintainable solution would be using templates, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). This is to primarily avoid HTML in the JS, which can get messy in the long run:

Assuming your data looks like:

```
{
  media : [
    {"displayName" : "", "hours" : ""},
    ...
  ]
}
```

Add this to your page. This will be your template. It will not render since it's inside `<script>` but it also won't run since the type is not `text/javascript`. Creating it is straightforward. If you want to see how it looks on the DOM while making them, just erase the script tags and you'll see it and a bunch of "{{ }}" tags.

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-chatinfo">
  {{#media}}
    <div class="chatInfo>
      <h6 id="{{@index}}">{{displayName}}</h6>
      <aside>
        <img src="/google.png" />
        <p>{{hours}}</p>
      </aside>
    </div>
  {{/media}}
</script>
```

Then your JS, short and lean.

```
// Get the template and compile it to a renderer function;
var template = $('#template-chatinfo');
var templateRenderer = Handlebars.compile(template);

// You might want to cache chatInfo
var chatInfo = $('#chatInfo');

// Pull out the url for easy reading and editing
var url = "/services/chatInfo.json?user=manual" + mediaTypes + locationTypes;    

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  // Render the data and append
  var renderedData = templateRenderer(data);
  $("<div />").html(renderedData).appendTo(chatInfo);
});
```

Comment: I really don't want to add another library is there another more jQuery out of the box solution?

Comment: @DelmonYoung jQuery has no built-in templating system, doing interpolation manually is reinventing the templating library. The closest you could get to a jQuery-ish template system is [iCanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/), a Mustache (where Handlebars is derrived from) plugin for jQuery.